# ASP Repeater not showing data in the correct order

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am trying to use an ASP.NET repeater control to show employee data and I want to show this data sorted by employee name. Even though the data I am getting from the database are in correct order after it bind to the repeater it shows in a different way (sort by employee id). How can this happen? Is there anyway I can stop this?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEmplist">
 <HeaderTemplate>
   <table class = "bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Employee No</th>
       <th>Employee Name</th>
       <th>Department Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
   <td><%# Eval("Empnum") %></td>
   <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
   <td><%# Eval("DptName") %></td>
   </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTempalate>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </FooterTempalate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# databind method

```
private void BindDataToGrid()
{
    DataTable empdt = BSL.GetEmployeeList(); // Just a another layer to connect with DB.
    rptEmplist.DataSource = empdt;// Data seems to be in the correct order in empdt
    rptEmplist.DataBind();
}
```

Data retrieving C#:

```
public static DataTabe GetEmployeeList()
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_EmpList"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return DSL.DBFactory.DBOperations.GetDataTable(cmd);
    }
}
```

Database stored procedure:

```
Create Proc Get_EmpList
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Employee 
    ORDER BY Name
END
```

Comment: Show query or SP of loading employees.

Comment: If the Repeater isn't showing data in the "correct order" you have not sorted your data in the correct order.

Comment: Have you checked whether the data in `empdt` is fine as you wish?

Comment: @un-lucky yeah its fine

Comment: Also show code of `GetEmployeeList`.

Comment: show code for this method DSL.DBFactory.DBOperations.GetDataTable

Comment: Have you tried not going through your DBOperations.GetDataTable?

Comment: Maybe it is off-topic but html seems to me corrupted: `<tbody>` should have closing tag. (possible html-processor misinterpretation)

Comment: @wolen sorry i have miss that part it was there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove "bootstrap-datatable datatable" from the table. Even though this class making the table sortable, It is overwriting the original sort-order I am feeding the asp:Repeater

[More about datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET repeater by default not support sorting, you can fetch the list and then add linq query to order the list

Comment: i do not think you have understood the question